# Jenkins com Spring Boot = ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, maven, jenkins

Estou com uma aplicação desenvolvida com spring-boot. Se eu chamo manualmente o jar gerado através do maven pelo comando java -jar, a aplicação inicia-se normalmente, e conseguimos usar por aqui.

Porém, para publicar nos ambientes (homologação, produção etc) nós utilizamos o Jenkins.

O processo consiste em:

1. Pegar o último commit no gitlab
2. Chamar o maven `clean package`. Com o Build realizado ele prossegue nos próximos passos:
3. Interromper a aplicação anterior em execução
4. Mover a aplicação anterior para um diretório de backup
5. Jogar a versão nova da aplicação
6. Executar (`nohup java -jar`)

Ele executa, o processo fica no ar, mas as requisições retornam erro 500:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1585850905158,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/endpoint/da/aplicacao"
}
```

Dá a entender que o processo fica preso (já que a aplicação está em execução) e o Jenkins encerra o job por timeout. Mas o que não consigo entender é que mesmo usando o `nohup`, esse processo ainda assim aparenta estar preso no job do jenkins.

Alguém já passou por algo parecido?

Comment: Verifique e poste os logs do servidor, não apenas o json de retorno da requisição

Comment: @nullptr No momento estou fazendo exatamente isso, porque a aplicação não estava gerando log.

Consegui um avanço usando `echo "java -jar nomedojar.jar" | at now` mas esbarrou em um erro que *acredito* que não está relacionado. 

Se de fato não estiver eu lanço a resolução!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguimos solucionar o problema, na parte de chamar a aplicação gerada:

Ao invés de apenas

```
nohup java -jar
```

foi acrescentado o `nice` para dar prioridade de execução:

```
nohup nice java -jar  $NOMEDOARQUIVOJAR
```

Com isto a aplicação foi publicada e já está em execução!